# Kubectl port-forwarding not working for IPv6 binding with socat

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, portforwarding, socat

I'm trying to understand why this particular `socat` command isn't working in my case where I run it in a IPv6 only Kubernetes cluster.

Cluster is build on top of AWS with Calico CNI & containerd. Provisioned using `kubeadm` and Kubernetes 1.21.

I have run the following `socat` command which binds to loopback interface `::1`,

```
kubectl --context=$CLUSTER1 run --image=alpine/socat socat -- tcp6-listen:15000,bind=\[::1\],fork,reuseaddr /dev/null
```

And then I try to `port-forward` and `curl` to `15000` port,

```
kubectl --context=$CLUSTER1 port-forward pod/socat 35000:15000 --address=::1
curl -ivg http://localhost:35000
```

I get the error,

```
Forwarding from [::1]:35000 -> 15000
Handling connection for 35000
E0830 17:09:59.604799   79802 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 35000 -> 15000: error forwarding port 15000 to pod a8ba619774234e73f4c1b4fe4ff47193af835cffc56cb6ad1a8f91e745ac74e9, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-8bade2c1-28c9-6776-5326-f10d55fd0ff9": failed to dial 15000: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:15000: connect: connection refused
```

Its listening to `15000` as,

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 ::1:15000               :::*                    LISTEN      1/socat
```

However if I run the following it works fine,

```
kubectl --context=$CLUSTER1 run --image=alpine/socat socat -- tcp6-listen:15000,bind=\[::\],fork,reuseaddr /dev/null
```

Not sure I understand why `port-forward` would fail for the loopback interface binding `::1` but not for catch all `::`. Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Comment: Could you please add following information to your post: how did you setup Kubernetes cluster (some cloud solution, bare metal etc.)? Which CNI and container runtime are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS. added more information. Happy to even share my github project if its thats required but that specifically deploys multiclusters.

Comment: You can share your GitHub project, it will be easier to understand overall use-case because I'm wondering what it the use case right now? ;)  Most of uses of `socat` that I know are related strict to Docker.

Comment: I have few questions anyway- did you configure / enabled somehow IPv6 on your cluster? If yes, how? Are you able to ping successfully IPv6 localhost on pod by running `ping -6 ::1`? 
The logs that you sent from `kubectl port-forward` - are you sure that you didn't cut them - seems there is no information about IPv6 forwarding - there should be also something like `connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found `.

Comment: @MikolajS. apologies for getting back to you late. Yes I do get "dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found". This is a fix that was introduced in containerd as part of https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blame/main/pkg/cri/server/sandbox_portforward_linux.go#L79

Comment: Bdw the error I sent above in my OP "dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:15000: connect: connection refused" is only pops in older containerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you running into a similar issue with your IPv6 only Kubernetes clusters heres what I have investigated found so far.

**Background:** It seems that this is a generic issue relating to IPv6 and CRI.
I was running `containerd` in my setup and `containerd` versions `1.5.0`-`1.5.2` added two PRs ([don't use socat for port forwarding](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/commit/11a78d9d0f1664466fa3fffebd8ff234f3ef2677) and [use happy-eyeballs for port-forwarding](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/commit/305b42583073aa1435d15ff5773c049827fa8d51)) which fixed a number of issues in IPv6 port-forwarding.

**Potential fix:** Further to pulling in `containerd` version `1.5.2` (as part of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) I was also getting the error `IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:15021: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found` when port-forwarding. This is caused by a DNS issue when resolving `localhost`. Hence I added `localhost` to resolve as `::1` in the host machine with the following command.

```
sed -i 's/::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback/::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback/' /etc/hosts
```

I think the important point here is that check your container runtimes to make sure IPv6 (tcp6 binding) is supported.

Comment: btw this gives error also:  IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:10000: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6 [::1]:10000: connect: connection refused

Comment: That might not be a related issue. Whats the root cause of yours ?